# Spring Boot integration test. How to test the 'DELETE' method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, junit

I'm using `Spring Boot 2.5.6` and `JUnit 4.13.2`. My task is to test the `DELETE` method

My REST controller:

```java
@RestController
public class DomainEndpoint {

    private final SomeService service;

    @DeleteMapping("/domain/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable long id) {
        service.delete(id);
    }
}
```

My test:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DomainEndpointTest {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate template;

    @MockBean
    SomeService service;

    @Test
    public void delete() {
        String url = "/domain/123";
        ResponseEntity<?> resp = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<>(""), String.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT, resp.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only solution for testing the 'DELETE' method, which I found, is:

```java
ResponseEntity<?> resp = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<>(""), String.class);
```

But params for body `new HttpEntity<>("")` and for return type `String.class` seem strange to me. Why should I use them? Can I do the same more straightway without passing unnecessary parameters?
On the other hand, `TestRestTemplate template` has a set of short and readable methods `delete()`. The problem with them - they return `void` and I can't check the response status code in this case.

The main question is how to test `DELETE` methods correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing in `new HttpEntity<>("")` `HttpEntity` has a special class variable you can use called `HttpEntity.EMPTY` for these situations. You can also use a return type of void.

```
ResponseEntity<Void> resp = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, HttpEntity.EMPTY, Void.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's much more readable compared with my example.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you could improve:

1. Don't provide a request entity – it is marked as `@Nullable`
2. Use `Void.class` as return type to express that you don't expect any response body

```java
ResponseEntity<Void> resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, null, Void.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is a more simplified example, but `null` scares me - it's not really readable. Do you know, are there any other methods that don't require unnecessary params and in particular the body?

Answer (score 0):

Others have given different options but if you want to use the the `delete` method - it internally handles the http error by throwing runtime error as you can see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5ea1cf532e08dbc9c79670040bb825d69878cf85/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java#L159). You can check for `HttpClientErrorException` or `HttpServerErrorException` by using [`assertDoesNotThrow`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertDoesNotThrow(org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)) from JUnit5

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in that case, I can’t check exact status == 204 (no content)

Comment: @Shailendra AFAIK `TestRestTemplate` does not throw any exceptions like `RestTemplate` does.

Comment: @slauth can you post the class for TestRestTemplate. Since you are using similar methods exposed by RestTemplate I am assuming it is something which extends RestTemplate or is it some custom implementation you have developed

Comment: @Shailendra [TestRestTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.java) is a wrapper around `RestTemplate` which sets a [NoOpResponseErrorHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.5.6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.java#L1034-L1040) on the wrapped `RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion RestTemplate.delete method is the one to use, return type is void but status other than 2XX will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in that case, I can’t check exact status == 204 (no content)

Comment: @user3075118 AFAIK `TestRestTemplate` does not throw any exceptions like `RestTemplate` does.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotin, feel free to use this extension methods :)

```kotlin
/**
 * Extension for using PUT (not provided by default)
 */
inline fun <RQ : Any, reified RP : Any> TestRestTemplate.putForEntity(url: String, payload: RQ): ResponseEntity<RP> =
    this.exchange(url, PUT, HttpEntity(payload))

/**
 * Extension for [TestRestTemplate] DELETE (not provided by default, whyever)
 */
inline fun <reified RQ : Any> TestRestTemplate.deleteForEntity(url: String): ResponseEntity<RQ> =
    this.exchange(url, DELETE)

/**
 * Extension for [TestRestTemplate] DELETE with payload (not provided by default, whyever)
 */
inline fun <reified RQ : Any, reified RP : Any> TestRestTemplate.deleteForEntity(
    url: String,
    payload: RQ
): ResponseEntity<RP> = this.exchange(url, DELETE, HttpEntity(payload))
```